# Assigning variables using loop or some other approach

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to put these codes in a for loop but I am having error. I know variables can not be assigned using loops or may be I am wrong and there is a way.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there an alternative approach to achieve the goal?

```
pm0=ax.annotate('', (35,10), textcoords='data',size=10)
pm1=ax.annotate('', (35,5), textcoords='data', size=10)
pm2=ax.annotate('', (35,0), textcoords='data', size=10)
pm3=ax.annotate('', (35,-5), textcoords='data',size=10)
pm4=ax.annotate('', (35,10), textcoords='data',size=10)


pm0.set_text(0)
pm1.set_text(1)
pm2.set_text(2)
pm3.set_text(3)
pm4.set_text(4)


#edit for i in range():
  for i in range(5):
     tag=10
     'pm'+str(i)=ax.annotate('', (35,tag), textcoords='data',size=10)
     tag=tag-5
     'pm'+str(i).set_text(i)
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862215/update-a-specific-annotation-in-matplotlib)

Comment: `for i in range(10, -5, 5):`?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the code to reflect the range.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to initialize all those `pm` objects through looping?

Comment: If so, you are much better off using a `list`.

Comment: yes instead of manually initializing the 'pm's. I want to alternatively do it using a loop. However the loop I have shown is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have implemented your `for` loop is wrong.

And doing something like `'pm'+str(i) = ...` will not work because it's a string. Not a variable.

So, using a `list`, you could do something like

```
pm = []
tag = 5
for i in range(5):
    pm[i] = ax.annotate('', (35,tag), textcoords='data',size=10)
    tag = tag - 5
    pm[i].set_text(1)
```

Also note that `tag` is initialised outside the loop. Otherwise, it will be reset in every iteration.